# Atomic instructions in semaphores

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I am confused what it means for semaphores to be atomic. The definition of wait and signal is below.

```
wait(S){
    while ( S<= 0)
        ; // Busy wait
        S--;
}


signal(S) {
    S++;
}
```

The book says

> all modifications to the integer value of the sophomore in the wait()
> and signal() operations must be executed atomically. That is, when one
> process modifies the semaphore value, no other process can
> simultaneously modify the same semaphore value

Does this mean that no other instructions can execute in-between `while(S<=0)` and `S--`? and at what point is the process done modifying the semaphore value? is this when it finally decrements S--?

Comment: 'The definition of wait and signal is below' - note that, while it might be some definition on some website, it's not universal.  Kernel synchro objects, like semaphores, do not always busy-wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that no other instructions can execute in-between while(S<=0) and S--?

No. It means all modifications (such as `S--`) must be done atomically, that is, no other process can simultaneously attempt to modify `S`, for example, by executing the `S++` in `signal`.

> At what point is the process done modifying the semaphore value? is this when it finally decrements S--?

Each modification must be atomic, as the explanation says. So it's done modifying the value at the end of each modification. It may modify it again, but that would be a distinct modification that must also be atomic.

You can think of an "atomic modification" as one that does not overlap any other atomic access or modification. Were `S++` and `S--` not atomic, an operation could get lost if, for example, two processes execute `S++` and their operations overlap. They could both read `S`, both increment `S`, then both write `S`, resulting in `S` only getting incremented once.

Answer (score 0):

What it means for any *operation* to be atomic is: Either it happens or it doesn't. If some thread A performs an atomic operation on some collection of data or on some object, and thread B examines the object/data, then thread B must either see the object/data as it was before the operation started or, as it was after the operation finished. "Atomic" means that it's impossible for thread B to see the object/data in a half-way done state.

We can provide atomicity by using `synchronized` blocks or `ReentrantLock` objects when accessing data, but if somebody tells you that some *object* is atomic, then what they are saying is, all of the operations that you can perform on it* are *automatically* guaranteed to be atomic, without you having to explicitly lock anything.

---

* Except maybe for special cases, called out in the object's documentation.